# Is there any import option available for Accumulo..?

Tags: mongodb, accumulo, nosql

I am new to Accumulo. We are migrating MongoDB to Accumulo database. we got a file with all tables information from mongoDB. Is there any option available in Accumulo to import the file and create the tables by its own? Through the API document I came to know that we can create table by shell script and also through programmatically. Can anyone tell me is there any import option available for Accumulo to import the file and create the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to do that.  MongoDb deals with JSON documents which have an entirely different layout/schema than the way Accumulo does things.  You could try using something like http://gora.apache.org/index.html, but that requires you to change the format of your MongoDB data.  If you can't do that than you'll more than likely you'll have to do this pragmatically yourself.